# I would like to avoid repeating codes

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I'm trying to build a web app for a friend of mine to help her in her business. The application is meant to help her monitor the number of Stock Keeping Unit in the storage of her little bakeshop.(or monitor how much sacks of flour, tray of eggs, cups of butter are left in her inventory). So to do this I've made a form for her. look:

```
<tr> <form method="POST" action="makeprod.php"> 
<td>Prodname</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="prodname"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td> <input type="int" name="quantity"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recipe 1: </td>   
<td>  
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 

$sql = "SELECT itemname FROM inventory"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='recipe1'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = ' ". $row ['itemname'] ."'>".$row['itemname']."</option>";    
            }
echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
<td>Qty</td>
<td> <input type="int" name="rec1qty"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recipe 2: </td>   
<td>  
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 

$sql = "SELECT itemname FROM inventory"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='recipe2'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = ' ". $row ['itemname'] ."' >".$row['itemname']."</option>";
            }
echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
<td>Qty</td>
<td> <input type="int" name="rec2qty"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recipe 3: </td>   
<td>  
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 

$sql = "SELECT itemname FROM inventory"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='recipe3'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = ' ". $row ['itemname'] ."'>".$row['itemname']."</option>";                
            }
echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
<td>Qty</td>
<td> <input type="int" name="rec3qty"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recipe 4: </td>   
<td>  
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 

$sql = "SELECT itemname FROM inventory"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='recipe4'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = ' ". $row ['itemname'] ."' >".$row['itemname']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
<td>Qty</td>
<td> <input type="int" name="rec4qty"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recipe 5: </td>   
<td>  
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 

$sql = "SELECT itemname FROM inventory"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='recipe5'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = ' ". $row ['itemname'] ."' >".$row['itemname']."</option>";                           ['itemname']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
<td>Qty</td>
<td> <input type="int" name="rec5qty"></td> 
</tr>


<tr> 
<td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td> 
</tr> 



</form>
</table>
```

What I'm trying to do in this form is to prompt her to record a product/pastry she's making, quantity and indicate the recipes/inventories that will cost her to make that product in that quantity so it will reduce those recipes from a database table I named 'inventory'(but this is for another story).

My issue is that I could not determine how many ingredients she'll need to make a single product and repeating a select option for the recipe 5 or 10 times seems to make my code look too dirty and it doesn't seem like efficient. What I want is a code that will help me display only the number of select options she needs in the form. So if a product she's making only has about 6 different ingredients then only 6 select option should be displayed. If 3, then only 3. 
It would help if I don't have to repeat this code from above to make my code atleast a bit cleaner:

```
<td>Recipe 1: </td>   
<td>  
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 

$sql = "SELECT itemname FROM inventory"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='recipe1'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value = ' ". $row ['itemname'] ."' >".$row['itemname']."</option>";                       
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I'm fairly new to PHP and doesn't know Javascript yet so I would prefer solution in HTML/PHP format but JS would also suffice. Thank you.

Comment: the item must have a specification... create a table... for example `ItemSpecification` which have columns of `itemID`, `ingredients`  table..... that'll solve your problem... in your item maintenance if you add an item you need to select only the ingredients needed to create that item, so there must be a lists of ingredients there...

Answer (score 0):

As per your title of question you have repeating code of sql connection in your code. Do avoid it by adding single connection file. Do create connection.php and add below code in it.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('inventory system'); 
?>
```

and include this file in your this working page as

```
include "connection.php";
```